# The center of a derived subgroup in an amenable group

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated amenable group and $G^{(i)}$ be a derived subgroup of $G$.

What can we say about the center of $G^{(i)}$? Can we say the center of $G^{(i)}$ is non-trivial for $i$ large enough?

Comment: Juschenko-Monod recently constructed a f.g. simple infinite amenable group $G$. Clearly it has trivial center and its derived subgroups all equal $G$. 

Comment: Grigorchuk group is amenable. One can  show (by virtue of the branch property) that the center of every derived subgroup is trivial.

Comment: Consider $S_5$. 

Comment: @Mark Sapir: An infinite group?

Comment: @Mahdi: You have not mentioned in your question that the requested group must be infinite, so Mark's answer is Ok.

Comment: There is no word "infinite" in the question. If you really want infinite, take the wreath product $S_5\wr {\mathbb Z}$. 
